# Choose at random from combinations

Tags: python

I can make a list of all combinations using `list(itertools.combinations(range(n), m))`  but this will typically be very large.

> Given `n` and `m`, how can I choose a combination uniformly at random without first constructing a massive list??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes

```
def random_combination(iterable, r):
    "Random selection from itertools.combinations(iterable, r)"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    indices = sorted(random.sample(xrange(n), r))
    return tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an improvement over using random.sample(values, r) directly in the case where values is a list or tuple already.

Comment: This does not answer the question, as tuple(iterable) does construct a massive list.

Comment: why are the indices sorted?

Comment: @Teque5 Because we want a random *combination*, not a random *permutation*. At the beginning of documentation page https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html under section "Combinatoric iterators:", you can see a comparison of `product()`, `permutations()`, `combinations()`, `combinations_with_replacement()`

Answer (score 13):

In the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module there is a recipe for returning a random combination from an iterable. Below are two versions of the code, one for Python 2.x and one for Python 3.x - in both cases you are using a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) which means that you are not creating a large iterable in memory.

#### Assumes Python 2.x

```
def random_combination(iterable, r):
    "Random selection from itertools.combinations(iterable, r)"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    indices = sorted(random.sample(xrange(n), r))
    return tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

In your case then it would be simple to do:

```
>>> import random
>>> def random_combination(iterable, r):
    "Random selection from itertools.combinations(iterable, r)"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    indices = sorted(random.sample(xrange(n), r))
    return tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
>>> n = 10
>>> m = 3
>>> print(random_combination(range(n), m))
(3, 5, 9) # Returns a random tuple with length 3 from the iterable range(10)
```

#### In the case of Python 3.x

In the case of Python 3.x you replace the `xrange` call with `range` but the use-case is still the same.

```
def random_combination(iterable, r):
    "Random selection from itertools.combinations(iterable, r)"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    indices = sorted(random.sample(range(n), r))
    return tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

Comment: If `iterable` has many iterations, doesn't `pool = tuple(iterable)` create a very large tuple in memory?

Answer (score 2):

A generator would be more memory efficient for iteration:

```py
def random_combination(iterable,r):
    i = 0
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    rng = range(n)
    while i < r:
        i += 1
        yield [pool[j] for j in random.sample(rng, r)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I've modified Jthorpe's generator in order to work when the number of combination you need greater than the length of iterator you pass:

```
def random_combination(iterable,r):
    i = 0
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    rng = range(n)
    while i < n**2/2:
        i += 1
        yield [pool[j] for j in random.sample(rng, r)]
```

Answer (score 1):

And so, this code maybe help you:

1. I created a empty list = "lista" to append results of np.random.permutation
2. "i" = iterator to control loop while
3. "r" = number of times to loop (in my case 1milion)
4. Into the while I did permutation of "20" numbers and get(output) a numpy array like: [20,3,5,8,19,7,5,...n20]

Observation:: there isn't permutation repeated...

Take this output is very

```
lista = []
i = 0
r = 1000000

while i < r:
    lista.append(np.random.permutation(20))
    i += 1

print(lista)
# thanks to my friend WIniston for asking about it
```

Results:::

[array([11, 15, 12, 18,  5,  0,  9,  8, 14, 13, 19, 10,  7, 16,  3,  1, 17,4,  6,  2]),
array([ 5, 15, 12,  4, 17, 16, 14,  7, 19,  1,  2, 10,  3,  0, 18,  6,  9, 11, 13,  8]),
array([16,  5, 12, 19, 18, 17,  7,  1, 10,  4, 11,  3,  0, 14, 15,  9,  6, 2, 13,  8]), ...

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the existing answers is they sample with replacement or wastefully discard duplicate samples. This is fine if you only want to draw one sample but not for drawing many samples (like I wanted to do!).

You can uniformly sample from the space of all combinations **very efficiently** by making use of Python's inbuilt methods.

```
from random import sample

def sample_from_all_combinations(all_items, num_samples = 10):
    """Randomly sample from the combination space"""
    num_items = len(all_items)
    num_combinations = 2 ** num_items
    num_samples = min(num_combinations, num_samples)

   
    samples = sample(range(1, num_combinations), k=num_samples)
    for combination_num in samples:
        items_subset = [
            all_items[item_idx]
            for item_idx, item_sampled in enumerate(
                format(combination_num, f"0{num_items}b")
            )
            if item_sampled == "1"
        ]
        yield items_subset
```

NOTE the above will fail with an `OverflowError` when `len(all_items) >= 64` because the Python ints `>= 2 ** 64` are too large to convert to C ssize_t. You can solve this by modifying the `sample` method from `random` to the following: (Don't forget to update the import to `from RandomLarge import sample`)

```
class RandomLarge(random.Random):
    """
    Clone of random inbuilt methods but modified to work with large numbers
    >= 2^64
    """

    def sample(self, population, k):
        """
        Chooses k unique random elements from a population sequence or set.

        Modified random sample method to work with large ranges (>= 2^64)
        """
        if isinstance(population, random._Set):
            population = tuple(population)
        if not isinstance(population, random._Sequence):
            raise TypeError(
                "Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d)."
            )
        randbelow = self._randbelow

        # NOTE this is the only line modified from the original function
        # n = len(population)
        n = population.stop - population.start

        if not 0 <= k <= n:
            raise ValueError("Sample larger than population or is negative")
        result = [None] * k
        setsize = 21  # size of a small set minus size of an empty list
        if k > 5:
            setsize += 4 ** random._ceil(
                random._log(k * 3, 4)
            )  # table size for big sets
        if n <= setsize:
            # An n-length list is smaller than a k-length set
            pool = list(population)
            for i in range(k):  # invariant:  non-selected at [0,n-i)
                j = randbelow(n - i)
                result[i] = pool[j]
                pool[j] = pool[n - i - 1]  # move non-selected item into vacancy
        else:
            selected = set()
            selected_add = selected.add
            for i in range(k):
                j = randbelow(n)
                while j in selected:
                    j = randbelow(n)
                selected_add(j)
                result[i] = population[j]
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

**To choose a random subset of multiple combinations**

You can keep picking random samples and discarding the ones that were already picked.

```
def random_subset_of_combos2(iterable, r, k):
    """Returns at most `n` random samples of
    `r` length (combinations of) subsequences of elements in `iterable`.
    """

    def random_combination(iterable, r):
        "Random selection from itertools.combinations(iterable, r)"
        pool = tuple(iterable)
        n = len(pool)
        indices = sorted(random.sample(range(n), r))
        return tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

    results = set()
    while True:
        new_combo = random_combination(iterable, r)

        if new_combo not in results:
            results.add(new_combo)

        if len(results) >= min(k, len(iterable)):
            break

    return results
```

This seems faster in most cases.

Alternatively, you can assign a index number to each combination, and create a list indexing the targeted number of random samples.

```
def random_subset_of_combos(iterable, r, k):
    """Returns at most `n` random samples of
    `r` length (combinations of) subsequences of elements in `iterable`.
    """
    max_combinations = math.comb(len(iterable), min(r, len(iterable)))
    k = min(k, max_combinations)   # Limit sample size to ...
    indexes = set(random.sample(range(max_combinations), k))
    max_idx = max(indexes)
    results = []
    for i, combo in zip(it.count(), it.combinations(iterable, r)):
        if i in indexes:
            results.append(combo)
        elif i > max_idx:
            break
    return results
```

Technically, this answer may not be what the OP asked for, but search engines (and at least three SO members) have considered this to be the same question.