# R Randomly select a combination

Tags: r

Let say I have a vector of numbers `x` that contains 10 numbers. I want to select a subset of N number M times and put it into a list object. How can I ensure what I pick is unique from the any elements within the list already? Note that order does not matter. So `c(1,0,3)` is the same as `c(3,0,1)`.

```
x = seq(1,10,1)
```

I can do this with `combn(x,N)` but in situation whens my `x` contains 10k or more elements, using combn and randomly select any of the ones within is computation infeasible.

Alternatively phrasing the question. I want to sample the output of `combn(x,N)` randomly without replacement. Is it possible without generating calling `combn` first?

Any ideas?

Comment: does `replicate(M, sample(x, size  = N, replace = FALSE), simplify = FALSE)` do what you want? Doesn't guarantee M samples will all be different, but could check afterwards

Comment: I don't think `replicate(M, sample(x, size = N, replace = FALSE), simplify = FALSE)` works. It can return `c(1,3) and c(3,1)`. To me those are the same. Note that if it returns `c(3,2)`, thats acceptable. The problem with replicate is it doesn't take in to account whats already generated...

Comment: It's not great, as it builds a list element-wise, but you could use a `while` loop: `x <- 1:10; 
N <- 4; 
M <- 10; 
out <- list(); 

while(length(out) < M){
    out <- c(out, unique(replicate(M - length(out), sort(sample(x, N)), simplify = FALSE)))
}; 

out`

Answer (score 2):

> I want to sample the output of combn(x,N) randomly without replacement. Is it possible without generating calling combn first?

I don't think so, not with the current state of 32-bit integers (and [`bit64`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/index.html), even as good as it is, doesn't catch everything).

Case in point: in order to be able to arbitrarily index the set returned by `combn(10000,4)`, you probably start by determining something as straight-forward/simple as "is the first of my four numbers a '1'". Knowing that the first `j` iterations of a combination generator will start with 1 (e.g., `1,2,3,4`, `1,2,3,5`, ..., `1,2,3,10000`), you think "all I need to do is check my desired index against this first set of 1s and iterate" (looking for 2s, 3s, etc). Unfortunately, with 10k and `N=5`, the first `4.162501e+14` rows start with "1". (This happens to be `choose(10000-1,5-1)`, which is not a coincidence.) You then have to do this again and again, and the count just goes higher.

This is well out of 32-bit integer-space. `N=6` escalates with `8.320840e+17` as the first set of 1s.

To perform "random access" on this space is rather insane, something where even (I suspect) native 64bit calculations will run out of space fairly quickly.

### If you cannot reduce your data size

I believe your most practical route will be to use @alistaire's suggested code in his comment:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- seq(1, 10000)
N <- 4
M <- 10
out <- list()
while(length(out) < M) {
  out <- c(out,
           unique(replicate(M - length(out), sort(sample(x, N)), simplify = FALSE)))
}
str(out)
# List of 10
#  $ : int [1:4] 2861 8302 9149 9370
#  $ : int [1:4] 1347 5191 6418 7365
#  $ : int [1:4] 4577 6570 7050 7189
#  $ : int [1:4] 2555 4623 9347 9398
#  $ : int [1:4] 1175 4750 5602 9783
#  $ : int [1:4] 1387 9041 9464 9887
#  $ : int [1:4] 825 3902 5142 9055
#  $ : int [1:4] 4470 7375 8109 8360
#  $ : int [1:4] 40 3882 6852 8327
#  $ : int [1:4] 74 2077 6116 9065
```

Or a slight adaptation (can be ~30% faster with much larger `N`,`M`):

```
set.seed(42)
N <- 8
M <- 100
out <- list()
while (length(out) < M) {
  out2 <- split(apply(matrix(sample(lenx, size = M*N, replace = TRUE),
                            nrow = M, ncol = N),
                     1, sort),
                rep(1:M, each = N))
  out <- c(out, out2[ !duplicated(out2) ])
}
```

If you know that `M*N < length(x)`, then you can use `replace=FALSE` instead and you should be guaranteed a single pass through the `while` loop.

### Even if you can *significantly* reduce your sample size

I've written a function that provides random access to combinations. However, the more I test it, the more I see that when it starts breaking down, it will do so without ensuring complete uniqueness of the indices and *without a guarantee of erring* when this happens. (So I'm not posting it. I can provide it offline if somebody is really curious. I did something similar with a [lazy `expand.grid`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36144255/3358272), but that was mathematically much simpler/tractable; and even then I haven't tested it with sets this large. Since you are looking for combinations, not permutations, I don't think it fits here.)

Bottom line: R may not be the place for this, unfortunately.

Comment: do you know any other tools that can do this? can python?

Comment: I don't know of any tools that do it, sorry. Even python's `itertools.combinations` is incremental, not random-access. The trick will be to mathematically map (in efficient time) an arbitrary integer to the matching set of indices. (It's easier in permutations, much harder with a combinations.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229796/choose-at-random-from-combinations wouldn't this work?

Comment: Doesn't `tuple(iterable)` (in that answer) enumerate the iterable, thereby exhausting memory here? (I don't know for certain, admittedly, but that's my understanding of it.)