# How do you efficiently random sample k combinations of size r form a list?

Tags: python, python-itertools

You can easily generate all possible combinations of the elements of a list using `itertools.combinations`. I am interested in then sampling only a handful of these as efficiently as possible. In some cases, this will mean having millions of combinations and only needing a handful of randomly selected ones.

```
import itertools

combinations = itertools.combinations(range(1, 30), 10)
```

I would like to sample e.g. 4 combinations out of all combinations stored in `combinations`.

EDIT: previous results can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22229796/choose-at-random-from-combinations) but do not strike me as very efficient.

Comment: thanks @Chris it doesn't strike me as overly efficient

Comment: You might `random.sample` indices, and then loop over the combinations **without creating an actual list** and choose the elements matching the indices.

Comment: I would consider reopening this question. It's not the same as the linked question. The OP wants **more than one** random combination, while the linked question is about **a single** random combination.

Answer (score 2):

Just picking 10 samples each time from the list would be most efficient way

```
>>> import random
>>> l = range(1, 30)
>>> 
>>> res = [random.sample(l, 10) for _ in range(4)]
>>> pprint(res)
[[23, 25, 27, 9, 8, 19, 3, 16, 26, 7],
 [6, 16, 5, 8, 22, 20, 15, 10, 12, 13],
 [28, 20, 3, 21, 29, 12, 7, 23, 2, 10],
 [18, 13, 29, 23, 19, 10, 27, 7, 17, 20]]
```

Comment: thanks, the point is that the list is extremely large. I'd rather not transform the iterable into a list since this would be highly inefficient.

Comment: Ah I see, you generate the combinations directly but this does not guarantee uniqueness of the resulting combinations, correct?

Comment: I have removed the unnecessary conversion to list

Comment: @MarkVerhagen `random.sample` would always return unique random elements

Comment: @PremAnand he means that 2 different calls to `sample` *might* return the exact same combination...

Comment: I get it now. But as we are generating a small list of samples, we can check if a newly generated sample matches an already generated one and regenerate if needed

Comment: yes, I agree, but I am still interested primarily in efficiently sampling an iterable, ideally without having to evaluate duplicates and possibly re-sample

Comment: @MarkVerhagen Sounds like [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) then.